# How do I make all div boxes shorten when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, addclass

I have the following code:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[href=#del]').click(function(){
            var myParent = $(this).closest('.box');
            myParent.slideUp(800, function(){
                myParent.remove();
    }); }); });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #444;
}
a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box3 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box4 {
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container {
    width: 660px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"><a href="#del">Toggle</a></div>
    <div class="box box2"><a href="#del">Toggle</a></div>
    <div class="box box3"><a href="#del">Toggle</a></div>
    <div class="box box4"><a href="#del">Toggle</a></div>
</div>
```

Question:

How can I use one anchor tag that has Toggle on it and when that is clicked all four boxes will reduce in size from height 300px to 150px? The code i have right now simply deletes it but i need it ot shrink the box to 150px from 300px.  and when clicked it again it should return to 300px.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you wanted, I provided 3 different alternatives. Hopefully one of them works for you. I see you just edited your post, my last example does what you want (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this animate what you are looking for. This will provide both the ability to toggle a single one or toggle all at the same time. If you only need it one way, you can remove one set of the anchors and the associated jquery.  If you "toggleAll" on one that is down, it will make them all up.. and vice versa.

http://jsfiddle.net/pb6fM/7/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[href=#toggleMe]').click(function () {
            var myParent = $(this).closest('.box');
            var h = "150px";
            if(myParent.height() == "150") { h = "300px"; }
            myParent.animate({
                height: h
            }, 800)
        });
        $('[href=#toggleAll]').click(function () {
            var boxes = $('.box');
            var h = "150px";
            if($(this).closest('.box').height() == "150") { h = "300px"; }
            boxes.animate({
                height: h
            }, 800)
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually need one link to it for all of them.  This is the one that I need: 
 

I think this animate what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/pb6fM/

        $("#slideEmUp").click(function(){
            $(".box").animate({height:'150px'}, 800)
        });

with anchors in each box... http://jsfiddle.net/pb6fM/3/

Here is if you just want to be able to make them toggle between 150 and 300...
http://jsfiddle.net/pb6fM/4/

Comment: thanks! that was nice but how do i make it go back to 300 when its clicked again?

Comment: which one? none of your fiddles have that.

Comment: Sorry, I was on the wrong link.  But it won't work on my site for some reason. I copied as you had it with the exception of the toggleMe

Comment: I figured out a work around.  How can I create another one where it's just one div and onclick it changes width ANd height?

Comment: Yes! thanks.  but how can i integrate this with the script I accepted, which is this one:  http://jsfiddle.net/pb6fM/7/

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Anyway, everything is there for you. Hopefully you can figure it out with that... if not, ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[href="#del"]').click(function () {
        var $divs = $(this).closest('.container').find('.box');
        $divs.css({
            'height': '150px'
        });
    });
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/jttwB/3/

Demo with animation `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/jttwB/2/

Comment: THanks! How do i do the reverse too? so if its at 150 and someone clicks again I would like to make it back at 300 and vice-versa.  Thanks!

Comment: THanks! but using that will prevent me from using .slideUp.  HOw can I use slideup with it?

Comment: I am interested in using slideup to slow down the effect.

Comment: @starbucks when you use the same anchor for sliding up the box and for changing the height, you will only be able to see slideUp effect, which will hide the .box,  I can help if you explain your desired effect

Comment: When the toggle button is clicked it has that slideup effect.  I need that to be slowed to 800, similar to the way one would do it if he/she were usign slideUP.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the $(this).closest part and add an .each.

```
$('.box').each(function (index, box) {
  $(box).slideUp(800, function() {
     $(box).remove();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a nicer effect... http://jsfiddle.net/KsV2L/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[href=#del]').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.box').animate({height:'150px',width:'0'},800,function(){$(this).remove()});
        $(this).closest('.container').find('.box').animate({height:'150px'},800);
}); });
```